# Low Humidity Entire Home

Tags: hvac

Past 3 weeks my humidity is hanging around 17-25 in each room. I see the water draining through the furnace humidifier so water is passing. Any ideas how to raise the humidity to 35-40?

Thanks

Comment: You may be getting a bad reading.  Unless you're in a desert climate, it's hard to get readings that low.  But verify that the season damper is in the right position.  There should be settings called "winter" and "summer", or something similar.  The damper needs to be open (winter) for the air to blow through the humidifier and back into the system.

Comment: Those seem like normal ranges in a cold climate. I have no whole house humidifier and my ecobee thermostat says 20% here in Boston.

Comment: You may need to have the humidifier serviced and have the media pad replaced.

Comment: A comment in addition to the answers; the house may not be well sealed and dry outside air is infiltrating . One source depends on if the furnace is in the heated space or in a garage or attic; if so it could be sucking in outside air.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a humidifier. Specially if outside is very cold (below 0°C), relative humidity in heated air gets very low, and your current humidifier can't simply recover all the humidity needed.